# & operator for bitwise programming returns wrong value (CPP)

Tags: c++, binary, bit-manipulation

I have this piece of code in cpp on Visual Studio

```
((handrule1 - maskRule1[0]) & test)
```

All of the variables are unsigned **int**.
Their values are respectively

- 66848250
- 50138096
- 0x80808080.

I keep getting value *zero* as the outcome for this line, which should not be possible.

How does this come?

I already tried working with *long unsigned* variables instead.

I am guessing that maybe I am doing something else wrong when choosing the data types.

Underneath you can find my full code.

Some of the variables are not defined but that's because they are already defined in another *cpp*-file we are not supposed to use.

```
void init(void) {
    int aa, ab, l, x = 0;
    for (int i = 4; i <= 13; i++) {
        aa = 13 - i;
        for (int j = (aa + 2) / 3; j <= i && j <= aa; j++) {
            ab = aa - j;
            for (int k = (ab + 1) / 2; k <= j && k <= ab; k++) {
                adj[x] = i + j - 8;
                l = ab - k; code[x++] = (((i - 4) * 7) + j) * 5 + k;
                //              printf("%d %d %d %d: %d\n", i, j, k, l, (((i-4)*7)+j)*5+k);
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}


char countSetBits(long long unsigned n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + countSetBits(n & (n - 1));
}


void init_set(void) {
    long long unsigned hand = 0;
    char honorPoints = 0;
    char nrOfSpades = 0;
    char nrOfHearts = 0;
    char nrOfDiamonds = 0;
    char nrOfClubs = 0;
    long long unsigned maskAces = 0x8004002001;
    long long unsigned maskKings = 0x10008004002;
    long long unsigned maskQueens = 0x20010008004;
    long long unsigned maskJacks = 0x40020010008;
    long long unsigned maskSpades = 0x1FFF;
    long long unsigned maskHearts = 0x3FFE000;
    long long unsigned maskDiamonds = 0x7FFC000000;
    long long unsigned maskClubs = 0xFFF8000000000;

    char upperbound[RU][4];
    char lowerbound[RU][4];
    unsigned int handrule1 = 0;
    unsigned int handrule2 = 0;
    unsigned int handrule3 = 0;
    unsigned int maskRule1[RU];
    unsigned int maskRule2[RU];
    unsigned int maskRule3[RU];
    unsigned int maskInverse = 0x00FF00FF;
    unsigned int test = 0x80808080;
    unsigned int result1 = 0;
    bool applicableRule = false;

    unsigned int fuck = 0xFF936636;

    result1 = fuck & test;



    for (int r = 0; r < nrr; r++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            upperbound[r][i] = 13;
            lowerbound[r][i] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int r = 0; r < nrr; r++)
    {
        if (res[r] != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < res[r]; i++)
            {
                upperbound[r][color[r][i]] = (char) nru[r][i];
                lowerbound[r][color[r][i]] = (char) nrl[r][i];
            }
        }
        maskRule1[r] = (((char) distl[r] << 24) | ((char) distu[r] << 16) | ((char) ahpl[r] << 8) | (char) ahpu[r]) ^ maskInverse;
        maskRule2[r] = ((lowerbound[r][0] << 24) | (upperbound[r][0] << 16) | (lowerbound[r][1] << 8) | upperbound[r][1]) ^ maskInverse;
        maskRule3[r] = ((lowerbound[r][2] << 24) | (upperbound[r][2] << 16) | (lowerbound[r][3] << 8) | upperbound[r][3]) ^ maskInverse;
    }


    int x[52], y, a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) x[i] = i;
    srand(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < CRD; i++) {
        for (int j = 52; --j > 1;) {
            y = rand() % j;
            a = x[y]; x[y] = x[j]; x[j] = a;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 13 * j; k < 13 * (j + 1); k++)
            {
                hand |= 1LLU << x[k];
            }

            //Counting honorpoints
            honorPoints = (countSetBits(hand & maskAces) * 4) + (countSetBits(hand & maskKings) * 3) + (countSetBits(hand & maskQueens) * 2) + (countSetBits(hand & maskJacks) * 1);
            hp[i][j] = (char) honorPoints;
            honorPoints = 0;


            //Counting distributions
            nrOfSpades = countSetBits(hand & maskSpades);
            nrOfHearts = countSetBits(hand & maskHearts);
            nrOfDiamonds = countSetBits(hand & maskDiamonds);
            nrOfClubs = countSetBits(hand & maskClubs);

            std::array<char, 4> arrayTest = { nrOfSpades, nrOfHearts, nrOfDiamonds, nrOfClubs };
            std::sort(arrayTest.begin(), arrayTest.end());

            char p = arrayTest[3];
            char o = arrayTest[2];
            char m = arrayTest[1];
            int test = (((p - 4) * 7) + o) * 5 + m;

            for (int x = 0; x < 39; x++)
            {
                if (code[x] == test)
                {
                    dis[i][j] = (char) x;
                }
            }

            //Counting opening bids
            ahp[i][j] = hp[i][j] + adj[dis[i][j]];
            if (ahp[i][j] < 0) ahp[i][j] = 0;

            handrule1 = ((dis[i][j] << 24) | (dis[i][j] << 16) | (ahp[i][j] << 8) | ahp[i][j]) ^ maskInverse;
            handrule2 = ((nrOfSpades << 24) | (nrOfSpades << 16) | (nrOfHearts << 8) | nrOfHearts) ^ maskInverse;
            handrule3 = ((nrOfDiamonds << 24) | (nrOfDiamonds << 16) | (nrOfClubs << 8) | nrOfClubs) ^ maskInverse;

            printf("%u \n", handrule1);
            printf("%u \n", maskRule1[0]);



            for (int r = 0; r < nrr; r++)
            {
                if ((((handrule1 - maskRule1[r]) & test) == 0) && (((handrule2 - maskRule2[r]) & test) == 0) && (((handrule3 - maskRule3[r]) & test) == 0))
                {
                    cnt[bid[r]][j]++;
                    applicableRule = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (applicableRule == false)
            {
                cnt[0][j]++;
            }

            applicableRule = false;
            handrule1 = 0;
            handrule2 = 0;
            handrule3 = 0;
            nrOfSpades = 0;
            nrOfHearts = 0;
            nrOfDiamonds = 0;
            nrOfClubs = 0;
            hand = 0;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The only way the result of masking with 0x80808080 could be 0 is if every byte of the result of subtraction has its high bit set to 0. But that is not the case with `66848250 - 50138096` (16710154 = 0x00FEFA0A = `00000000 11111110 11111010 00001010`), so the result of masking should be 0x00808000 (8421376) instead of 0. So clearly `handrule1` and/or `maskRule1[0]` do not have the values you claim they have. Step through your code with a debugger and validate every assignment and calculation is producing what you are expecting.

Comment: I found the problem. The values of `handrule1` and `maskRule[0]` were right. It was actually my `test` variable that had a wrong value. Apparently there already was a variable named `test` in my program and so it returned different values. Thanks for helping me!